# The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled error

Tags: php, mongodb, iis

I installed mongodb drivers in my php and the php info showed mongo db is enabled but the php project still saying **'The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled'**.

**php info**

```
MongoDB support enabled
MongoDB extension version   1.6.0alpha1
MongoDB extension stability alpha
libbson bundled version 1.13.0
libmongoc bundled version   1.13.0
libmongoc SSL   enabled
libmongoc SSL library   OpenSSL
libmongoc crypto    enabled
libmongoc crypto library    libcrypto
libmongoc crypto system profile disabled
libmongoc SASL  enabled
libmongoc ICU   disabled
libmongoc compression   disabled
```

**my project running in the iis**

> The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled

Comment: Where is the `php.ini` file in which the extension is enabled located? In a typical Linux+Apache setup, it's common for there to be separate CLI and Apache versions of this file. It's possible that you only have the extension enabled in the CLI, and not for IIS. I recommend checking whether or not this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally after so much efforts i thrown in i finally fixed it.the problem was because i used a new extension (mongo_db.dll).when i used mongo.dll which is the older version my problem was solved. the link to the old mongo is https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.6.16/windows